How to dynamically create a TWebFrame using GetClass in TMS WEB Core?
I've made the following function that creates and loads a TWebFrame into my form:
procedure LoadHomePage();
var
  FramePage: TWebFrame;
begin
  FramePage := TFrame_Home.Create(Self);

  FramePage.Name := 'layHome';
  FramePage.Visible := False;
  FramePage.Parent := LayoutContainer;
  FramePage.Align := alClient;
  FramePage.LoadFromForm;
end;

This works without any issues, but I might not always know what the class is for the page. So let's say I don't know that the class is TFrame_Home, but I am able to get TFrame_Home from somewhere as a string. How can I dynamically create this same page without knowing that the class name is TFrame_Home?
I've tried to do this using the GetClass function, but it's not really working. This is what I've tried:
procedure LoadHomePageDynamically();
var
  FrameClass: TPersistentClass;
  FramePage: TWebFrame;
begin
  FrameClass := GetClass('TFrame_Home');
  FramePage := TWebFrame(FrameClass.Create);

  FramePage.Name := 'layHome';
  FramePage.Visible := False;
  FramePage.Parent := LayoutContainer;
  FramePage.Align := alClient;
  FramePage.LoadFromForm;
end;

The code compiles without any errors, but in run-time when I call the function, then I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild') | TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild') at Object.UpdateElement (http://localhost:8000/DelphiWebsite/DelphiWebsite.js:68452:32) at Object.EndUpdate (http://localhost:8000/DelphiWebsite/DelphiWebsite.js:36935:43) at Object.EndUpdate (http://localhost:8000/DelphiWebsite/DelphiWebsite.js:37513:31) at Object.AfterLoadDFMValues (http://localhost:8000/DelphiWebsite/DelphiWebsite.js:15413:12) at Object.LoadDFMValues (http://localhost:8000/DelphiWebsite/DelphiWebsite.js:85042:26) at Object.LoadFromForm (http://localhost:8000/DelphiWebsite/DelphiWebsite.js:45329:12) at LoadHomePageDynamically (http://localhost:8000/DelphiWebsite/DelphiWebsite.js:101898:19) at Object.CreatePages (http://localhost:8000/DelphiWebsite/DelphiWebsite.js:101912:7) at Object.WebFormCreate (http://localhost:8000/DelphiWebsite/DelphiWebsite.js:101831:12) at Object.cb (http://localhost:8000/DelphiWebsite/DelphiWebsite.js:245:19)
at http://localhost:8000/DelphiWebsite/DelphiWebsite.js [68452:32]

So it appears like the error is coming from the FramePage.LoadFromForm code, but I need this code in order to load the frame and for it to appear on the form.
I also have the frame's class name registered at the bottom of the frame's .pas file using the below code:
initialization
  RegisterClasses([TFrame_Home]);


Note that I'm very new to using GetClass, FindClass and RTTI. I haven't done a lot with it yet. I'm also not sure if what I'm doing is even remotely correct or possible.
The reason why I want to do it this way using GetClass is because I might have hundreds of different frames and I don't want to individually "hardcode" create them. So if I could create them using the class name instead, then that would be perfect.

So how can I dynamically create a TWebFrame without knowing the class name?

Your LoadHomePage and LoadHomePageDynamically are calling different constructors. First one is calling virtual constructor from TComponent (or similar class hierarchy) which takes owner as a parameter and second one is calling base TObject constructor as TPersistent class does not have any other constructors.
So, when you call TWebFrame(FrameClass.Create) you will end up with improperly initialized TWebFrame instance as you will not call appropriate virtual constructor, hence the error you are seeing.
To call appropriate constructor you need to declare TWebFrameClass metaclass which will be able to call appropriate constructor and properly initialize your web frame instance.
type
  TWebFrameClass = class of TWebFrame;

procedure LoadHomePageDynamically();
var
  FrameClass: TWebFrameClass;
  FramePage: TWebFrame;
begin
  FrameClass := TWebFrameClass(GetClass('TFrame_Home'));
  FramePage := FrameClass.Create(Self);

  FramePage.Name := 'layHome';
  FramePage.Visible := False;
  FramePage.Parent := LayoutContainer;
  FramePage.Align := alClient;
  FramePage.LoadFromForm;
end;

If TWebFrame is TComponent descendant, you can also use TComponentClass, instead of declaring TWebFrameClass. However, in that case you will need to use typecast around FrameClass.Create(Self);. when assigning frame instance to FramePage variable.
